# Aws availability zone

Tags: amazon-ec2

Is it possible to specify an AWS availability zone of us-west-2b when creating an instance on amazon? I can only specify us-west-2 but it randomly picks a,b or c. I want to attach a volume to the instance which runs in us-west-2b and instances in us-west-2a cannot attach.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Show your code. You might need to do this by specifying the VPC subnet in us-west-2b.

Comment: aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-d2xxxxxx \
    --key-name pankaj-ec2-key --instance-type t2.micro\
    --security-groups sshgroup default

Comment: availability zone si specified using aws configure

Comment: I think the option is --placement AvailabilityZone=us-west-2c . Should have looked harder

Answer (score 1):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) allows you to send API requests to AWS from any computer.

When configuring the CLI with the `aws configure` command, you can provide:

- Access Key + Secret Key credentials
- Default region (eg `us-west-2)
- Output format

All AWS services reside in a **region** (eg `us-west-2`). When sending an API request to AWS, the region is used to determine [which endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) should receive the request.

The region can be specified using the `--region` parameter, or the Default Region specified via `aws configure`.

When launching an Amazon EC2 instance with the `aws ec2 run-instances` command, the Availability Zone (eg `us-west-2b`) when using old-fashioned EC2-Classic or **a Subnet can be specified when using VPC**. Subnets belong to a particular region and a particular Availability Zone. Therefore, **specifying a Subnet also selects the Availability Zone**.

For example:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --subnet-id subnet-6e7f829e --image-id ami-abc12345 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name MyKeyPair --security-group-ids sg-903004f8
```

Amazon EBS volumes can only be attached to Amazon EC2 instances **within the same Availability Zone**. To change the Availability Zone for an EBS volume, take a snapshot, then create a new volume from the snapshot while specifying the desired Availability Zone.